# Setting background-image for disabled inputs

Tags: css, input, textarea, background-image

I'm trying to add a small lock icon to a disabled textfield / text input.

When setting the background image

```
form input[disabled]:not([type=radio]), textarea[disabled] {
background-image: url('data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/4QAWRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAAAAAAAAD/4gxYSUNDX1BST0ZJTEUAAQEAAAxITGlubwIQAABtbnRyUkdCIFhZWiAHzgACAAkABgAxAABhY3NwTVNGVAAAAABJRUMgc1JHQgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA9tYAAQAAAADTLUhQICAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABFjcHJ0AAABUAAAADNkZXNjAAABhAAAAGx3dHB0AAAB8AAAABRia3B0AAACBAAAABRyWFlaAAACGAAAABRnWFlaAAACLAAAABRiWFlaAAACQAAAABRkbW5kAAACVAAAAHBkbWRkAAACxAAAAIh2dWVkAAADTAAAAIZ2aWV3AAAD1AAAACRsdW1pAAAD+AAAABRtZWFzAAAEDAAAACR0ZWNoAAAEMAAAAAxyVFJDAAAEPAAACAxnVFJDAAAEPAAACAxiVFJDAAAEPAAACAx0ZXh0AAAAAENvcHlyaWdodCAoYykgMTk5OCBIZXdsZXR0LVBhY2thcmQgQ29tcGFueQAAZGVzYwAAAAAAAAASc1JHQiBJRUM2MTk2Ni0yLjEAAAAAAAAAAAAAABJzUkdCIElFQzYxOTY2LTIuMQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAWFlaIAAAAAAAAPNRAAEAAAABFsxYWVogAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFhZWiAAAAAAAABvogAAOPUAAAOQWFlaIAAAAAAAAGKZAAC3hQAAGNpYWVogAAAAAAAAJKAAAA+EAAC2z2Rlc2MAAAAAAAAAFklFQyBodHRwOi8vd3d3LmllYy5jaAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFklFQyBodHRwOi8vd3d3LmllYy5jaAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABkZXNjAAAAAAAAAC5JRUMgNjE5NjYtMi4xIERlZmF1bHQgUkdCIGNvbG91ciBzcGFjZSAtIHNSR0IAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC5JRUMgNjE5NjYtMi4xIERlZmF1bHQgUkdCIGNvbG91ciBzcGFjZSAtIHNSR0IAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAZGVzYwAAAAAAAAAsUmVmZXJlbmNlIFZpZXdpbmcgQ29uZGl0aW9uIGluIElFQzYxOTY2LTIuMQAAAAAAAAAAAAAALFJlZmVyZW5jZSBWaWV3aW5nIENvbmRpdGlvbiBpbiBJRUM2MTk2Ni0yLjEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHZpZXcAAAAAABOk/gAUXy4AEM8UAAPtzAAEEwsAA1yeAAAAAVhZWiAAAAAAAEwJVgBQAAAAVx/nbWVhcwAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAo8AAAACc2lnIAAAAABDUlQgY3VydgAAAAAAAAQAAAAABQAKAA8AFAAZAB4AIwAoAC0AMgA3ADsAQABFAEoATwBUAFkAXgBjAGgAbQByAHcAfACBAIYAiwCQAJUAmgCfAKQAqQCuALIAtwC8AMEAxgDLANAA1QDbAOAA5QDrAPAA9gD7AQEBBwENARMBGQEfASUBKwEyATgBPgFFAUwBUgFZAWABZwFuAXUBfAGDAYsBkgGaAaEBqQGxAbkBwQHJAdEB2QHhAekB8gH6AgMCDAIUAh0CJgIvAjgCQQJLAlQCXQJnAnECegKEAo4CmAKiAqwCtgLBAssC1QLgAusC9QMAAwsDFgMhAy0DOANDA08DWgNmA3IDfgOKA5YDogOuA7oDxwPTA+AD7AP5BAYEEwQgBC0EOwRIBFUEYwRxBH4EjASaBKgEtgTEBNME4QTwBP4FDQUcBSsFOgVJBVgFZwV3BYYFlgWmBbUFxQXVBeUF9gYGBhYGJwY3BkgGWQZqBnsGjAadBq8GwAbRBuMG9QcHBxkHKwc9B08HYQd0B4YHmQesB78H0gflB/gICwgfCDIIRghaCG4IggiWCKoIvgjSCOcI+wkQCSUJOglPCWQJeQmPCaQJugnPCeUJ+woRCicKPQpUCmoKgQqYCq4KxQrcCvMLCwsiCzkLUQtpC4ALmAuwC8gL4Qv5DBIMKgxDDFwMdQyODKcMwAzZDPMNDQ0mDUANWg10DY4NqQ3DDd4N+A4TDi4OSQ5kDn8Omw62DtIO7g8JDyUPQQ9eD3oPlg+zD88P7BAJECYQQxBhEH4QmxC5ENcQ9RETETERTxFtEYwRqhHJEegSBxImEkUSZBKEEqMSwxLjEwMTIxNDE2MTgxOkE8UT5RQGFCcUSRRqFIsUrRTOFPAVEhU0FVYVeBWbFb0V4BYDFiYWSRZsFo8WshbWFvoXHRdBF2UXiReuF9IX9xgbGEAYZRiKGK8Y1Rj6GSAZRRlrGZEZtxndGgQaKhpRGncanhrFGuwbFBs7G2MbihuyG9ocAhwqHFIcexyjHMwc9R0eHUcdcB2ZHcMd7B4WHkAeah6UHr4e6R8THz4faR+UH78f6iAVIEEgbCCYIMQg8CEcIUghdSGhIc4h+yInIlUigiKvIt0jCiM4I2YjlCPCI/AkHyRNJHwkqyTaJQklOCVoJZclxyX3JicmVyaHJrcm6CcYJ0kneierJ9woDSg/KHEooijUKQYpOClrKZ0p0CoCKjUqaCqbKs8rAis2K2krnSvRLAUsOSxuLKIs1y0MLUEtdi2rLeEuFi5MLoIuty7uLyQvWi+RL8cv/jA1MGwwpDDbMRIxSjGCMbox8jIqMmMymzLUMw0zRjN/M7gz8TQrNGU0njTYNRM1TTWHNcI1/TY3NnI2rjbpNyQ3YDecN9c4FDhQOIw4yDkFOUI5fzm8Ofk6Njp0OrI67zstO2s7qjvoPCc8ZTykPOM9Ij1hPaE94D4gPmA+oD7gPyE/YT+iP+JAI0BkQKZA50EpQWpBrEHuQjBCckK1QvdDOkN9Q8BEA0RHRIpEzkUSRVVFmkXeRiJGZ0arRvBHNUd7R8BIBUhLSJFI10kdSWNJqUnwSjdKfUrESwxLU0uaS+JMKkxyTLpNAk1KTZNN3E4lTm5Ot08AT0lPk0/dUCdQcVC7UQZRUFGbUeZSMVJ8UsdTE1NfU6pT9lRCVI9U21UoVXVVwlYPVlxWqVb3V0RXklfgWC9YfVjLWRpZaVm4WgdaVlqmWvVbRVuVW+VcNVyGXNZdJ114XcleGl5sXr1fD19hX7NgBWBXYKpg/GFPYaJh9WJJYpxi8GNDY5dj62RAZJRk6WU9ZZJl52Y9ZpJm6Gc9Z5Nn6Wg/aJZo7GlDaZpp8WpIap9q92tPa6dr/2xXbK9tCG1gbbluEm5rbsRvHm94b9FwK3CGcOBxOnGVcfByS3KmcwFzXXO4dBR0cHTMdSh1hXXhdj52m3b4d1Z3s3gReG54zHkqeYl553pGeqV7BHtje8J8IXyBfOF9QX2hfgF+Yn7CfyN/hH/lgEeAqIEKgWuBzYIwgpKC9INXg7qEHYSAhOOFR4Wrhg6GcobXhzuHn4gEiGmIzokziZmJ/opkisqLMIuWi/yMY4zKjTGNmI3/jmaOzo82j56QBpBukNaRP5GokhGSepLjk02TtpQglIqU9JVflcmWNJaflwqXdZfgmEyYuJkkmZCZ/JpomtWbQpuvnByciZz3nWSd0p5Anq6fHZ+Ln/qgaaDYoUehtqImopajBqN2o+akVqTHpTilqaYapoum/adup+CoUqjEqTepqaocqo+rAqt1q+msXKzQrUStuK4trqGvFq+LsACwdbDqsWCx1rJLssKzOLOutCW0nLUTtYq2AbZ5tvC3aLfguFm40blKucK6O7q1uy67p7whvJu9Fb2Pvgq+hL7/v3q/9cBwwOzBZ8Hjwl/C28NYw9TEUcTOxUvFyMZGxsPHQce/yD3IvMk6ybnKOMq3yzbLtsw1zLXNNc21zjbOts83z7jQOdC60TzRvtI/0sHTRNPG1EnUy9VO1dHWVdbY11zX4Nhk2OjZbNnx2nba+9uA3AXcit0Q3ZbeHN6i3ynfr+A24L3hROHM4lPi2+Nj4+vkc+T85YTmDeaW5x/nqegy6LzpRunQ6lvq5etw6/vshu0R7ZzuKO6070DvzPBY8OXxcvH/8ozzGfOn9DT0wvVQ9d72bfb794r4Gfio+Tj5x/pX+uf7d/wH/Jj9Kf26/kv+3P9t////2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkSEw8UHRofHh0aHBwgJC4nICIsIxwcKDcpLDAxNDQ0Hyc5PTgyPC4zNDL/2wBDAQkJCQwLDBgNDRgyIRwhMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjL/wAARCAAOAA4DASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQAAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4+Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3+Pn6/8QAHwEAAwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSExBhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3+Pn6/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwDvdT1rR9R8UXcGqapPHp9rEqRRQySRq0uW3liuCSMKB25rT8Fa1b3CX+ni+kuvs1wfs7yZLtAQpUk9Tgkrk88Vy+pfCbUL3Vby7TVLZFnneUKUbIDHOK2/BvgG88MajcXU1/BOJYfLCohGPmznmueLqc+ux7lelg/q/uzd7LTpfr0P/9k=');
background-position: right top;
background: #F7F7F7;
color: #000000;
border: 1px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #757575;
}
```

The css for the background-image isn't reflected on the webpage when using chrome or firefox.  Does anyone know of any other ways to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try changing the background attribute to background-color to make sure it's not wiping out the image.

Answer (score 0):

- There is a typo in your content type: `image/jepg`
- This kind of data URI will not work in IE < 8, and in IE8 only if it's up to 32kb large.
- `[disabled]` will not work in IE7 because it doesn't know the attribute selector.
- `:not` is [not supported by IE < 9](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html).

Comment: @Michael which part of the thing isn't working - the whole selector, or just the background image? If it's the background image, maybe try generating the image again? http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/cgi/data/data

Comment: The background-image isn't showing up in the disabled text area.  I believe the selector is working because I am able to change the background color and border etc.  The image should be fine too because it shows up in non-disabled inputs/textareas.